# Checking for an MX record with getmxrr() or dns_get_record() returns incorrect information

Tags: php, dns, mx-record, nslookup, dns-get-record

I am currently attempting to check the validity of an email address by first checking if an MX record exists, using `getmxrr()` or `dns_get_record()` with PHP 7 on a DigitalOcean droplet.

In my example (which returns the incorrect response), I am attempting to check an email address on the domain “nuwatches.com”. Using `dns_get_record(”nuwatches.com”, DNS_ALL)`, I’m returned an array that DOES include an MX record, even though I know this does not exist in reality:

```
[5] => Array (
    [host] => nuwatches.com.com
    [class] => IN
    [ttl] => 27
    [type] => MX
    [pri] => 1
    [target] => mail.user-mail.net
)
```

However, if I use `nslookup` directly from the console on the DigitalOcean droplet, I’m correctly told that no MX record exists.

In addition, if I run the `dns_get_record()` function on a different droplet, or using an online PHP code runner, I’m also given the correct answer (which is that no MX record exists).

I’ve spoken to DigitalOcean support and they suggest there’s something strange happening with PHP on that particular droplet, perhaps with caching issues, but I can’t at all figure out what might be causing the discrepancy, especially as I'm not caching anything myself.

As it stands, my only option to get the correct response on this droplet is to run `nslookup` and then parse the result, but I would like to use `dns_get_record()` if possible.

I’d appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Any solutions for this issue? In my case I can't see MX records with getmxrr(), but other services like mxtoolbox.com see them...

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar problems with `dns_get_record()` when calling it with the default value for record type `DNS_ANY` or when calling it with `DNS_ALL`.

[php dns_get_records( host, type ) is returning false with type=DNS_ALL but returns DNS records with DNS_TXT or DNS_A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72745677/php-dns-get-records-host-type-is-returning-false-with-type-dns-all-but-retur)

A solution that worked for me was to use:

```
dns_get_record( ”nuwatches.com”, DNS_MX )
```

I am still investigating the reason behind this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a 3rd party PHP library for that.
I've just tested it and it worked for me.

**[bluelibraries/dns](https://github.com/bluelibraries/dns)**

### sample

```php
use BlueLibraries\Dns\Facade\DNS;
use BlueLibraries\Dns\Records\RecordTypes;

$records = DNS::getRecords('nuwatches.com', RecordTypes::MX);

print_r($records);
```

#### result

```
Array
(
    [0] => BlueLibraries\Dns\Records\Types\MX Object
        (
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [host] => nuwatches.com
                    [ttl] => 3600
                    [class] => IN
                    [type] => MX
                    [pri] => 1
                    [target] => localhost
                )

        )

)
```